# What is the role of a circuit in zero knowledge rollups

Tags: ethereumjs, zksnark, rollups, zksync

I am a student currently pursuing my bachelors degree in technology, for my final year project. I am trying to create a zk-rollup poc for nfts, I have came across different implementation of rollup such as zksync and hermez protocols. I have done some research on building circuits for zkp using circom, but got stuck on fewer things

1. what is a circuit in zkp, is it only created for genarating proofs or it actually does all the process like adding the state changes to merkle tree
2. How is data availability made to ethereum, while reading some source docs I found that there are using calldata to store data but how they can be retrieved after storing it. Any example of calldata usage will be highly helpful.

Thanks everyone please help me